# Under what conditions does univariate variable prescreening fail? (random forest modeling)

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, univariate

Univariate statistical methods are often used to prescreen variables for possible inclusion in a model. For example, running random forests (RF) with only a single predictor at a time to prescreen variables, and selecting the variables based on a minimum Model Improvement Ratio score (MIR). The prescreened variables are then used in full RF models, with the prescreened variables again being tested for inclusion in the final model using MIR, with a subset of them typically being used.

My question is, under what conditions can this method fail to identify an important predictor? I'm sure a scenario can be created where an interaction effect is very important to a model, when the two associated predictors aren't detected as being useful when tested individually.  Is there a write-up on the conditions under which this prescreening is not appropriate, and how this could be known in advance?